# Rails routing REST with 2 or more items (Get and Post) custome URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, crud

I have a rails app that I would like to fix up. I am new to rails and do not know how to do this correctly. There is a database, model, and table that has many products. I created a way for a user to select 2 of those products from a dropdown that contains database entries. The user selects 2 products and then can compare them, I set up a view to display the specs to of the 2 products.

I am sure I am not following REST and not doing this right though it is working. Using the CRUD operations in Rails allows show and index, it also makes a URL that has the product id for one such product, I have not done it like this. Instead I pass an instance variable @product to productpicker controller/view form and use the params returned to look up database items to display in the comparison controller/view.

What I would like to accomplish:

1. a URL that looks like www.domain.com/oneproduct-vs-someotherprodct
2. a correct RESTfull way to fetch 2 products at once and show them
3. a sitemap that has all the links so I can provide them to google for SEO purposes. I assume the links will be dynamic and no will know that I have someproduct-vs-someotherproduct, so a site map is essential as is the text in the url above.
4. Proper white-listing of variables where necessary

Please help guide me in the right direction. Much appreicated guys, thanks for helping out a noob.

What I have done so far:

Routes:

```
get 'products/pickproducts'

post 'products/pickproducts', to: 'products#compareproducts'
```

Is it possible to add slugs here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way I'd do it.

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :products do # sets up the usual index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy
  get :compare, on: :collection
end
```

You will be able to access this path at `www.example.com/products/compare`, and when you have two product IDs to pass in, you can just append them to the URL: `www.example.com/products/compare?product_id1=345&product_id2=432`.

(Note that this is a `GET` request; `POST` is usually reserved by convention for *requests that create records* -  and `PUT` or `PATCH` for requests that *update* records. `GET` requests are usually the only ones that expect parameters in the address itself, too.)

**app/controllers/products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def compare
    @products = Product.all
    @product1 = Product.find(params[:product_id1]) rescue nil
    @product2 = Product.find(params[:product_id2]) rescue nil
  end
  # ...
end
```

**app/views/products/compare.html.erb**

(Disclaimer: I haven't used a form to create a `GET` request before, but I *think* this should work:)

```
<%= form_tag compare_products_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag :product_id1, options_from_collection_for_select(@products, 'id', 'name') %>
  <%= select_tag :product_id2, options_from_collection_for_select(@products, 'id', 'name') %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<% if @product1 && @product2 %>
  <%= @product1.id %>
  <%= @product1.brand %>
  <%= @product1.modname %>
  <hr>
  <%= @product2.id %>
  <%= @product2.brand %>
  <%= @product2.modname %>
<% else %>
  Please select two products above to compare.
<% end %>
```

---

The one part I'm not sure about is the SEO and webcrawlers - I haven't got into these particularly heavily so can't really advise. You *might* be able to set this up as your route instead:

```
get ':product_id1-vs-:product_id2' => 'products#compare'
```

... and then, if it works, the URLs would be `www.example.com/products/-vs-` (yeah, I know that's not great) and `www.example.com/products/345-vs-432`. However, `compare_products_path` will now require two arguments, and I'm not sure how you'd get your selected products into the URL that the form points at.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I left the program as is, and use the parameterize method to make a string "someproduct-vs-someotherproduct", is there a way to dynamically append that string to the view comparison's URL? if there was a way to do that I think I could leave it as is.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that problem myself - still not sure how you'd do it. The only idea I've had so far is to change the `<form>` tag with Javascript.

Comment: I am trying to implement what you have said here but I am getting chopped up somewhere. Do you mind explaining where "name" comes from in the options_from_collection_for_select?

Comment: Oh, I don't know what your field names are. I was just assuming your primary key would be `id` and your display name would be `name`. You should replace that with whatever they actually have.

Comment: I tried putting in a field name, one of the field names is brand, it gives me the same error ?

Comment: I have never used "options_from_collection_for_select" and do not understand what needs to go in "name" other than a field name.

Comment: See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select. The first argument is the collection; the second is the method to send to each item to get the `value` attribute of the `option` tag; and the third is the method to send to each item to get the text to display inside the `option` tag.